# Get Files in date range doesn't work Powershell

Tags: powershell

I try to get files in a date range and i follow somes topics to make it good but ....
I don't understand one thing ....

My problem :
I search for a file contain a string, but i have more than one file who contains it so i decide to filter by date range because i know this one. 
this is my code :

```
$Datestart=" Start of date range "; ex : 20042020_1500
$Dateend=" End of date range "; ex : 20042020_1510
$MessageId="The string i want"; ex : 2015195558.22355@wsfrf1412
$Target="my repository"; ex : D:/Test\

$DateStartok = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Datestart, "ddMMyyyy_HHmm", [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture);

$DateEndok = [DateTime]::ParseExact($Dateend, "ddMMyyyy_HHmm", [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture);

Select-String -path $TargetDir*.txt -pattern $MessageId |
   Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $DateStartOk -AND $_.CreationTime -lt $DateEndOK };
```

My interpretation of this code is :

Return me the file who contain the string i want during the date range i specified.

This code will work with variables but i try with real informations to test it:
Result is :
This code return no result.

I try with this :

```
Select-String -path $TargetDir*.txt -pattern $MessageId |
   Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $DateEndOK };
```

The script return me the good file.

I try with this :

```
Select-String -path $TargetDir*.txt -pattern $MessageId |
   Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $DateStartOk };
```

the script return me the same result, so it work too....

For my example, the file was created at 15h05 the 20/04/2020
And i try with the range 15h00--->15h10

in normal time the script have to return a result in the first case but not in the second...

I try again with the same code than my two examples but with -gt instead of -lt and i have no result for this ....

Can you help me ? 
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Get-ChildItem` to first get a collection of files that fall in the date range and use `Select-String` on those to find the string you are looking for.

Something like this:

```
$DateStart = Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 4 -Day 20 -Hour 15 -Minute 0  -Second 0   # "Start of date range"
$DateEnd   = Get-Date -Year 2020 -Month 4 -Day 20 -Hour 15 -Minute 10 -Second 0   # "End of date range"
$MessageId = '2015195558.22355@wsfrf1412'                                         # "The string i want"
$Source    = 'D:\Test'                                                            # "my repository"

# you may want to add the -Recurse switch here if the code should also look inside subfolders
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter '*.txt' -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $DateStart -and $_.CreationTime -lt $DateEnd } |
    Select-String -Pattern $MessageId -SimpleMatch | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

Also, I think you actually want to use the date range on the `LastWriteTime` property, not the `CreationTime`. The LastWriteTime is the date when the file is last updated. The CreationTime can be much older..

<sup>P.S. In your code, you are defining `$Target`, but later on you are using an undefined variable `$TargetDir`</sup>

Comment: Hello, Thank you, it work good, I tried with GetChild-Item but no result again with this, but with your code it's ok... Ps : Yes $Target is a mistake from me but it didn't do the error in the xcript so work fine. Have a nice day

Comment: @JohanPoggi Thanks for the nice feedback. Stay safe!